# .net maui, how to make button's command executable even if Enabled=false for its element

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I want to make user know why the button is disabled with a short message when user clicks on it.

One way of doing that is to mimic button disabled state by custom styling, but problem is it can differ from system styling which could change from platform to platform and os versions etc. Also if it's composite multi-element custom button, it makes things really complicated. So don't want to go this way.

My expectation was that I can let the command run anyway by setting `CanExecute` to delegate that always returns `true`.

Example (with help of [mvvm framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand))

```
[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(AlwaysCanExecute))]
private void MyCommand()
{
    ...
}

private bool AlwaysCanExecute() => true;
```

However it does not work: both `AlwaysCanExecute` and `MyCommand` runs only when element that the command bound to is enabled, once I disable it (Enabled="False") it does even try to run `AlwaysCanExecute`. Is it how it's supposed to work or I'm missing something?

If it's by design, is there any way to do that w/o custom styling mimicking disabled styling?

Comment: By design, so no way to get the command to execute. You could attach a tap gesture recognizer to the button.

Comment: Put the button inside a Grid layout, put it behind a StackLayout using the z-index feature of the Grid and use a trigger to change visibility and the enable status of the  StackLayout depending on the button `IsEnabled` property, also attach a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the StackLayout that will call another command o event that will show the message

Comment: To me, sounds more like a requirement issue as designed to be "Clickable" and "Disabled" at the same time. Generally, validation can also be added in the beginning of the execute method, or try to talk to consultants or users to make life easier.

Comment: That's by design. As per the [documentation of the command interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#icommands), you shouldn't attempt to use a Button's `IsEnabled` property when using the command interface. `CanExecute` is part of that. There's even a warning that states: "Do not use the IsEnabled property of Button if you're using the command interface."

Comment: @FabriBertani it works, simple design that did not come to my mind for some reason. Please add it as an answer. It's workaround and bit hacky, it it's simple and it really works

Comment: The simplest solution is to wrap the command with a another command that will show a message if the wrapped command can not be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 potential solution here.

The first, similar to a comment left on the post: you could have a your button in a grid where a second "invisible style" button lays atop your current button. The second button being the one that displays your message. No need to use the Z-index; you could simply have this button's visibility bound to a property that is the inverse of your current button's IsEnabled. That way, this button never interferes when your current button is enabled.

The second solution, would be to utilise the [Tooltips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/tooltips?view=net-maui-7.0) provided out of the box. This renders differently depending on the platform. In all cases it has a native look but ultimately, it would boil down to how you want this experience to be styled.